# How to have an element be position fixed for only part of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidemenu that needs to scroll with the page, but beneath it are more elements. The menu scrolls through these elements and this is not what I want. So when the menu hits the element beneath it, it should stop scrolling with the page.

How can this be done? Do I need to use jquery? Or can I use a css only trick, maybe something with z-index?

Comment: We will need to see some code to be able to help and a JSFiddle would make things easier too and more likely to return you a response.

Comment: I would suggest javascript/jQuery - read into `scrollTop();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/3w1pvhsx/

JQUERY

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
  $("#menu").css("visible","none");
  $("#menu").css("position","fixed");
  pos = Math.ceil($("#menu").offset().top);
  pos2 = Math.ceil($("#text2").offset().top);
  if(pos>pos2){
    $("#menu").css("position","relative");
  }
  else{
    $("#menu").css("position","fixed");
  }
  $("#menu").show();
});
```

CSS

```
#menu{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  position:fixed;
  height:20px;
}
.text{
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 margin-left:50%;
}
```

HTML
See https://jsfiddle.net/3w1pvhsx/